# Override XMLHTTPRequest Calls

Tags: javascript, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to override XMLHTTPRequest behaviour in order to delegate Ajax requests to a phonegap plugin in case of a native app (Which will handle https certificate authentication challenge).

In case the application is running in native container,

- Cancel current HTTP call
- Call the phonegap plugin in order to execute HTTP call
- Receive HTTP response
- Trigger an event in current XMLHttpRequest instance with http response elements

My apps must run on a native et web context using the same source code. Developers can do Ajax calls seamlessly.

Here is a sample code for what I'm trying to do:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
    var me = this;
    me.abort();
    cordova.exec(function(httpresult) {             
        // Query success
        // httpresult object contains http response headers and content
        // How can onreadystatechange be triggered ???
        me.onreadystatechange(httpresult);
    }, function(httpresult) {
        // Query failure
    }, "QueryPlugin", "query", [{
        url: me.url,
        method: me.method,
        data: me.data
        // other http query params
    }]);
}
```

I don't know how to pass http headers and content properly to the current XMLHttpRequest instance and how to trigger onreadystatechange method.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova/phonegap redefines XMLHttpRequest object out of the box for some of the platforms providing additional functionality, for example for Windows Phone it does it in the following way

https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-js/blob/master/lib/wp7/plugin/wp7/XHRPatch.js

Probably you would like to do something in the same manner or extend existing implementation for your platform.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm indeed going to use a redefinition of XMLHTTPRequest. Here's a redefinition that works just great: https://github.com/philikon/MockHttpRequest

Comment: Did you found a solution for that?
I try to override the origin header for request on mobile devices. Can you help?